# writing files to a remote http server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a virtual directory with read and write access to everyone on Machine B. I am running web application 1 on Machine A. Now the requirement is to upload a file to remote http location from this web application. Machine A web application i is configured with anonymous authentication.

i am not able to implement the above requirement successfully. Please suggest whether this approach is correct or not?

```
 public override bool UploadFile()
    {
        byte[] postData;
        try
        {
            postData = this.FileData;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                client.UploadData(this.UrlString, "PUT", postData);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to upload", ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

[i have tried the example given in the below location](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETRemoteUploadAndDown-a80b7cb5)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETRemoteUploadAndDown-a80b7cb5

unfortunately i could not able to make it work. I am using IIS7 on both machine A & B
Please suggest.

Comment: "read access to everyone on Machine B" have you given write access?

Comment: Is there anything running on the server which knows to write the contents of this `PUT` request to a file?  Maybe you're looking for a WebDAV setup?

Comment: Can't you just use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) to do this?

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: I have given read and write access on Machine B virtual folder.

Comment: @David: is it possible to achieve without webDav?

Comment: @icemaind: can File.copy be used to move file to a remote server with a http url?

Comment: @KishoreBorra: `File.Copy` doesn't work over HTTP, no.  This is possible without WebDAV, but likely requires an application on the server listening for requests and writing them to the file system.  You can't just push data to a web server by itself and expect it to modify the local file system.

Comment: Could you create a WCF and host as Windows Service in machine B? Then you could add a net tcp binding and it will work.